# Chrome Crashing

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has been quitting on me a lot recently, it will just freeze and the page will go away and go straight to my desktop.  I downloaded the newest operating system to see if that would help and it has not.  Any advice?

```
 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: And what is "the newest operating system"?

Comment: 16.04 for ubuntu

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I edited it as such

Comment: Could you please try to run Chrome in a terminal to look for interesting error messages? The program executable name is `google-chrome-stable`.